# Functions to remove extra faces & fix normals? | Marvelous Designer FBX to Blender Workflow

Tags: modeling, faces, workflow, normals

[edit] Here's the project file: [image]

While I realize that the answer may be staring me in the face, I've also sunk a lot of time into this with no real progress.

I'm working on using custom Marvelous Designer clothing for Character Creator, and am using Blender (ultimately) for clean-up & efficiency adjustments. While I'm able to export an FBX from Marvelous that has each fabric as a separate object, the hang up is that those individual pieces *seem* to have two layers of faces **or** vertex groups with faces connected in weird ways... and when removing duplicate vertices, it doesn't really clear up the face issue.

[image]

What I'm left with are wonky normals and a mesh that cannot be smoothed out. I know the appropriate workflow is to simply retopoligize; but I wanted to check if anyone had a solution to the weird face groups and/or normals issue.

[image]

[image]

[Edit] **The solution turned out to be** in part, update my blender from 2.83 to the latest LTS. In that case, I was able to use 'Shift+N' to resolve most of the face issues. There is still a lot of manual work to be done.

I did come across another odd case of Marvelous designer clothing, when imported it looked like this:
[image]

The file itself was a lot cleaner. All the faces were set with the normal orientation facing inward, which was easy to correct. But even afterwards it still had the odd issue.

[image]

In this case, it turns out that the solution was in the material settings. I switched the blend mode to opaque and checked backface culling - I didn't need the transparency since that can be expensive to render in-game.

[image]

The end result:
[image]

Comment: AFAIK you can create 2 layers of fabric in MD to give the cloth some thickness. So there are often 2 mesh layers, one for the inside, and one for the outside. (But I've also seen cloth models with only 1 mesh layer.) The mesh parts are usually not merged and loose. In best case the meshes do not overlap. But it looks like they do in your case. In Blender you don't need 2 layers. You can delete the inner mesh parts. Select one vert & press L to select the whole part. Then X to remove. Keep only the outer (blue) parts. Finally, just add a *Solidify* modifier to give the cloth thickness again.

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE. can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: @Blunder It did export two layers with some of the fabric pieces which I was able to remove this way, but it still resulted in this outcome.
I will have to try different export settings from Marvelous though to see if the results vary. I'll keep the thread up-to-date on what I find.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Here's that link: https://blend-exchange.com/b/y874XoQk

Comment: @BluViolets i took a look and you could select all and press `Shift+N` to make sure to recalculate Normals. Then unfortunately for the rest of the weird red patches of overlapping faces, there is no automated way to fix them, you have to manually go through all of them and delete the overlapping faces and then readd faces.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie thanks! I updated my blender from 2.83 (what I'd been using when starting this project) to the latest LTS and recaulculating normals finally worked for me as well. Still not sure why it wasn't working in 2.83, but I am relieved that it's working as expected.